# How to group data by date and get the mode at the same time using python

Tags: python

I'm cleaning weather data and I have several fields with categorical values. In the data set one date can have several values where I need to group them using their date and at the same time I need to get the mode for that specific date

`temp_df2 = temp_df2.groupby(['Time']).apply(pd.DataFrame.mode)`

[image: Data]

Comment: So, may I know what the problem is?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about this?:

`temp_df2 = temp_df2.groupby(['Time']).apply(pd.DataFrame.mode())`

Where you replace `mode` with `mode()`?